# Why is the render so weird?

Tags: rendering, glass

So I finished making the bottle, and added a simple red liquid to it. On the render preview, it looked great, but when I hit actual render, it became weird like this:
[image]

If I add smooth shading then it looks like this:
[image]

**How do I fix the reflections and the little stripes around the liquid?** I rendered it in these settings: *Samples: 300 render, 300 preview...Resolution: 800x800px (80%)*

Comment: The solution you sent me caused another problem with the liquid: http://i.imgur.com/mWqtIIM.png Now there is some weird black circle around it, and the reflections are too bright

Comment: That weird black circle looks like a refraction issue, try playing with the IOR of the liquid and of the bottle.

Comment: whenever you have a round glossy object it *needs* to be smooth shaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you mesh has hard edges on surfaces.
Go to edit mode, then on the left of blenders GUI in the tabs go to "Shading/UV" overthere under faces click smooth..and hit render again ..voila